# Restar dos SUM de tablas diferentes en Mysql

Tags: mysql

Tengo 2 tablas(Productos y Abonos), de la tabla Productos hago un SUM de la columna Precio, este resultado se lo resto a otro SUM de la columna Abono de la tabla Abonos.Pero no me esta dando los resultados correctos (es decir, si el SUM de precios es 52 y el SUM de abono es 10, el resultado me da 116).

```
SELECT SUM(productos.precio)-SUM(abono.Abono) AS resta 
FROM productos,abono 
WHERE productos.Id_cliente=2 and abono.Id_cliente=2;
```

Tomando en cuenta el id del cliente en ambas tablas para indicar que cliente Abona a su cuenta.

Intentè de esta otra manera:

```
SELECT (SUM(productos.precio)-SUM(abono.Abono)) AS resta 
FROM productos 
INNER JOIN abono ON productos.Id_cliente=abono.Id_cliente 
WHERE productos.Id_cliente=2;
```

Comment: ¿Se vende una única unidad de cada producto? Fíjate que estás sumando directamente los precios sin multiplicarlos por la cantidad vendida. Si dejas en tu pregunta el SQL que genera la tabla y algún dato de prueba, con un ejemplo calculado manualmente por tí, podré ver más claro cómo ayudarte. Saludos.